# c# Crystal Reports call

Tags: c#, sql

I have looked about everywhere, lots of research, tested many different peoples code, anstill have the same issue trying to open a crystal report sending two parameters to the report.

Everytime it opens it opens blank.  I hit refresh on the viewer, and it asks for parameters and opens just fine.

My code is listed below.  I am on a deadline.  I would appreciate if someone could look at this and help me.  I am lost after many hours of research.

```
        ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
        cryRpt.Load(@"C:\reports\myReport.rpt");
        cryRpt.SetDatabaseLogon("", "", "MyServer", "MyDB");
        ConnectionInfo c = new ConnectionInfo();
        c.ServerName = "MyServer";
        c.IntegratedSecurity = true;
        c.DatabaseName = "MyDB";

        CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Tables CrTables = cryRpt.Database.Tables;

        foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in CrTables)
        {
            CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
            crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = c;
            CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo);
        }

        cryRpt.SetParameterValue("@parmBeginDate", "01-01-2010");
        cryRpt.SetParameterValue("@parmEndDate", "03-30-2013");
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
        crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
        crystalReportViewer1.Show();
```

Comment: I edited to remove company specific database names , paths and servers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to declare my parameters AFTER I loaded the report into the crystalreportviewer.  Then refresh.  It worked great after that.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

This will happen if your report has one or more sub-reports. Try refactoring setting the report connection to a method. You can then enumerate the sub-report collection and set the connection information for each sub-report. I also prefer setting the **ConnectionInfo** object directly.

```
foreach (ReportDocument subReport in report.Subreports)
{
    SetDatabaseConnectionInformation(subReport);
}

private void SetDatabaseConnectionInformation(ReportDocument report)
{
    ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
    connectionInfo.AllowCustomConnection = true;
    connectionInfo.Type = ConnectionInfoType.SQL;
    connectionInfo.ServerName = MyServer;
    connectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = (true or false);
    connectionInfo.UserID = MyUserName;
    connectionInfo.Password = MyPassword;
    foreach (Table table in report.Database.Tables)
    {
        TableLogOnInfo tableLogOnInfo = table.LogOnInfo;
        tableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = connectionInfo;
        table.ApplyLogOnInfo(tableLogOnInfo);
    }
}
```

Also, if you have multiple data sources you need to set the **InternalConnectionInfo** class to individually set the connection information for the different data sources.

Comment: its a basic report with no sub reports

Comment: i can attach the report privately if you wish

Comment: Are MyServer, and MyDB the same database and server the report was built with? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227750%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: yes they are the same info